# How to query a TSQL col that contain " E "?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use `openquery` to create a table from SSAS (tabular cube) using DAX SUMMARIZE function. The column names that come with "[" and "]". I load column names into a temp table, but I can't access a specific table because it contains "E".

[image]

How can I write a query that can call for that special name type?

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE [Report Date] = 'xxxx'

SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE [[Report Date]] = 'xxxx'

SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE '[Report Date]' = 'xxxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using square brackets to quote a name that starts/ends in a square bracket, it looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE [[Report Date]]] = 'xxxx'
```

Reason being SQLServer doesn't care about opening square brackets if the name is quoted with a square bracket, but it does care about closing square brackets, so the closing square bracket that is part of the name needs to be escaped by doubling it up

The name thus is:

```
[[Report Date]]]
1233333333333445
```

1. open square bracket - quote identifier
2. open square bracket - the OSB that is part of the name
3. the words Report Date
4. double close square bracket - tell sql server about a close square bracket in the name
5. single close square bracket - end of quoted identifier

It's probably clearest to use ANSI quotes for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE "[Report Date]" = 'xxxx'
```

Avoid using `'` at all times when quoting names - they are for denoting strings, not identifiers. It might work to say `select x as 'hello world'` but it doesn't work to then try and use it in a query like `WHERE 'hello world' = ...` because it's interpreted as a string, not an identifier. Avoiding using it to quote identifiers in a select means you won't then mistakenly do it in eg a where clause